# Searching features by text and Zoom to extent of that feature in Cesium

Tags: cesium

I am using Cesium and I am new to it. I want to implement searching by certain attribute for example Name of the point. The result obtained should be the map zoomed into the point found. How can this be implemented.

Comment: What documentation have you read on this?  Where does that documentation leave you stuck?

Comment: Have you read about Cesium's [Geocoder](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Geocoder.html), [GeocoderService](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/GeocoderService.html), and [GeocoderViewModel](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/GeocoderViewModel.html)?  Stack Exchange is not a format for asking how to code a complex thing from scratch.  Use documentation to get started, and ask a more specific question when you get stuck.  Thanks!